# Get record name from a table that is referenced by ID with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, linq-to-entities

I encountered a problem, while doing some MVC testing.  So at the moment I have 2 tables, one called Leagues and one called Teams.

In Leagues I have LeagueID, LeagueName, and in Teams I have TeamID and TeamName.  Then I have another table called LeagueTeams which contains the LeagueTeamID, fk_LeagueID and fk_TeamID.

Now in my ViewData, I am referencing the Teams table so I have something like the following :-

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Teams) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeamName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LeagueTeams)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Now item.LeagueTeams is for example 1, which is the LeagueTeamID.  How can I get the League Name in this code?  Do I need to call a reference to something else, or create a linq statement?

UPDATE

I came up with this in my Controller but I still have a problem :-

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        TeamsData model = new TeamsData();

        var _Teams = (from t in db.Teams
                          from tl in db.LeagueTeams
                          where t.LeagueTeams.Contains(tl.League.LeagueID)
                          select t);

        model.Teams = _Teams;


        return View(model);


    }
```

However the code is throwing an error on tl.League.LeagueID, telling me :-

"cannot convert from 'int' to 'MyProject.Models.LeagueTeam'"

Any help would really be appreciated since I seem to be a bit lost here!

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

```
where t.LeagueTeams.Any(lt => lt.LeagueID == tl.League.LeagueID)
```

Edit:

```
    var _Teams = (from t in db.Teams
                  from tl in t.LeagueTeams
                  select tl.League.Name);
```

Comment: EXCELLENT that works, and how can I call it from the View then?  At the moment I have         @foreach (var item in Model.Teams) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeamName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LeagueTeams)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I recommend you get all the data you need in the controller. That is usually a much saner approach than querying in the view.

Comment: Yes I am trying to get everything in the controller, but I cannot seem to get the LeagueName.  How can I display the LeagueName in the View?

Comment: I added a new proposal. This might be what you want.

Comment: still a problem :( Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MyProject.Models.Team>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)..........Cannot remove the IEnumerable since then the View will not work

Comment: Yeah my query returns just the name because it is sample code. You need to think through this yourself because only you know precisely what you want to accomplish. I just try to put the right tools in your hand.

Comment: Thanks for your help usr, I will take it from here